# How to design Firebase database for Booking app?

Tags: database, firebase

I am new to databases. In learning purposes I'm creating a simple booking app (with React-Redux) that would have tennis courts to book. First, you choose day and time, then you can see the exact courts (the courts are different) available for that date and time.

I was reading docs in Firebase and answers to similar questions in SO but I'm still confused. 
Could you tell me, how can I structure my Firebase database and query only available courts for each date and time, or at least, what should I study to be able to make it by myself?

Comment: Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's going to be impossible for us to suggest a structure without understanding the entire scope of the projects - you best bet here on SO, and to avoid having the question closed or getting downvotes as you are, is to include some code of what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not have anything to do with Firebase platform necessarily.

Since you mentioned that you are new to working with databases in general, It is good for you to search for "How to design a schemaless/NoSql database". There are tons of material online for you to read. Firebase has offered two separate solutions when it comes to databases:

1. Firestore
2. Realtime database

and both of them are NoSql databases.

here is a list of things I think you have to do in order to enable yourself in this matter:

1. Understand what are schemaless databases and their differences with SQL databases.
2. Come up with a structure for your data which represent the flow of data and the use frequency of them properly in case of your application , including the indexes and etc.
3. Pick one of the two aforementioned databases of Firebase which suits you best after realizing how they differ from each other.

   4. The rest is easy as eating a piece of cake!

Comment: @Xenia I have an additional suggestion. Go through the Firebase [Getting Started Guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup/) as they will not only help you get your app started but will also familiarize yourself with Firebase by doing simple reading and writing. Once you have that down, you will be better equipped to make a decision about which one and also, and just as important, how to structure your database.